# ¿Cuál sería el significado de "book print" en español?

Tags: traducción

Recientemente he encontrado este cartel sobre el alfabeto hebreo y deseo realizar la traducción de "book print" (ver encabezado de la primera columna) al español pero no encuentro un equivalente.

[image]

Alguno tienen una idea de como traducirlo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En español se le llama habitualmente **“letra de imprenta”** a la forma de las letras que aparece impresa generalmente en libros u otros materiales (se da por sobreentendido que se trata de un tipo de letra habitual para la lectura, es decir, con una tipografía más o menos común). Se la llama también “letra de molde”, pero esa expresión es mucho menos frecuente.

La letra escrita a mano se denomina “(letra) manuscrita”. En otros contextos se le dice “(letra) cursiva”, aunque hoy en día la cursiva propiamente dicha (es decir, donde las palabras se escriben sin levantar la pluma o el lápiz, uniendo las letras entre sí) no es tan popular como antes.

Por lo tanto *“book print”* debería traducirse como “letra de imprenta”. Las otras dos podrían traducirse como “manuscrita” y “cursiva”.